# Python using `!=`, `or` and `while`

Tags: python

For example, I want to run the loop when `choice` isn't  neither`1` nor `2`. So my code is like this:

```
choice = int(input('Enter a number: '))

while choice != 1 or choice != 2:
    # some code here
```

Now here is my question, whatever `choice` is `1`, `2`, or other, this loop will still run because choice can't be `1` and `2` at once.  And I don't know why does this also don't work:

```
while choice != 1 or 2:
    # some code here
```

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are using `or` , you have to use `and` since you want to check that `choice` is not `1` **and** `choice` is not `2` either. Example -

```
while choice != 1 and choice != 2:
```

Comment: hah it must be late ... some how it completely escaped me that he should be using and :P

Answer (score 1):

Every number is either not 1 *or* not 2.  What you want is for it to be not 1 *and* not 2.  So do `while choice != 1 and choice != 2`.

You can also do `while choice not in (1, 2)`, which is more easily extensible to a larger set of values to check against.

Answer (score 1):

```
while choice not in [1,2]:
```

or

```
while choice != 1 or choice != 2:
```

the problem is

```
while choice != 1 or 2:
```

is evaluated left to right so pretend choice = 3

```
while 3 != 1 or 2: = > while (3 != 1) or 2: ==> while (False) or 2: =>> 2 is always true so it doesnt work
```

Comment: The second code line is exactly the same as in the code in Question. And it will not work.