# While loop running even after condition is False

Tags: python, while-loop

I want the user to input either 1, 2 or 3. But when I test it and enter 1,2 or 3 it still runs even though the condition is False. I keep changing the condition from and's and or's but I can't seem to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
def get_input():
    user_input = input("Enter a number 1,2 or 3:  ")

    while  (user_input != 1) and (user_input != 2) and (user_input != 3) :
        print('Invaild input!')
        user_input = input("Enter a number 1,2 or 3 : ")
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The program is running as it has been told to do. Thus the expression is not false.

Comment: You have values of different types -- `"1" != 1 # True`

Comment: Thanks Jonathan, but how to deal with the user entering a string or a number that isnt 1 2 or 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python using \`!=\`, \`or\` and \`while\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835527/python-using-or-and-while)

Comment: You need to either test against strings or convert the input to an int.

Comment: There is probably a dupe of this somewhere, but that proposed dupe definitely isnt it.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading strings, you should either convert it, or use strings.  So the condition should be

```
(user_input != "1") and (user_input != "2") and (user_input != "3")
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the value returned from `input()` is a string (enclosed by quote marks), not an integer.

ie.

`"1"` is not the same thing as `1`

To fix it change this line.

```
while  (user_input != "1") and (user_input != "2") and (user_input != "3") :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change the input data type to integer from string or rather use "2" instead of 2 in your code

For Using It Without Changing The Data Type:

```
def get_input():
user_input = input("Enter a number 1,2 or 3:  ")

while  (user_input != "1") and (user_input != "2") and (user_input != "3") :
    print('Invaild input!')
    user_input = input("Enter a number 1,2 or 3 : ")
```

For changing data type to int:

```
def get_input():
user_input = int(input("Enter a number 1,2 or 3:  "))

while  (user_input != 1) and (user_input != 2) and (user_input != 3) :
    print('Invaild input!')
    user_input = int(input("Enter a number 1,2 or 3 : "))
```